# Handling type mappings when using the spread operator

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-testing-library

I have this setup function in my tests and I want to be able to pass the typing along when its called so I can have intelisense without having to ignore it in eslint.

```
function setup(): SomeType {
  return {
    user: userEvent.setup(),
    ...render(
      <Assessment />
    ),
  };
}
```

I just want to know what should SomeType be?

I tried:

```
interface SomeType {
  [Key in keyof RenderResult]: Result
  user: UserEvent,
}
```

But that obviously is wrong as id need to get the type of each property to handle that and i was hoping there was a less hacky way.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own questions....

```
interface Setup extends RenderResult {
  user: UserEvent;
}
function setup(): Setup {
  return {
    user: userEvent.setup(),
    ...render(
      <Assessment />
    ),
  };
}
```